# System.InvalidOperationException: <html xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to add a product to QuickBooks, but I get this error:

Error:

{System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderFaultInfo.Read3_FaultInfo()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   at Intuit.Ipp.Utility.XmlObjectSerializer.Deserialize[T](String message)}

Here is my code:

```
    private Item BuildInventoryItemAddRq(JMAOrderDetail _OrderItem)
    {
        // Make sure we have a SKU value
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_OrderItem.Sku))
        {
            ErrorMessageDataSource.Insert(new ErrorMessage(MessageSeverity.Info, "QBO", "OrderItemId " + _OrderItem.OrderId.ToString() + " has no SKU.  Using default QuickBooks Item Name of 'Unknown Item'"));
            _OrderItem.Sku = "Unknown Item";
        }

        // create the item as an inventoryitem in Quickbooks
        Item QBItem = new Item();
        QBItem.Active = true;
        QBItem.Name = _OrderItem.Sku;
        string _ItemName = IsProductVariantNamed(_OrderItem);
        //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ItemName))
        //{  // its a variant product
        //    _ItemName += "(" + _ItemName + ")";
        //    if (_OrderItem != null)
        //        QBItem.QtyOnHand = _OrderItem.StockQuantity;
        //    else
        //        QBItem.QtyOnHand = 0;
        //}
        //else
        //{ // regular product
        //    if (_OrderItem != null)
        //        QBItem.QtyOnHand = _OrderItem.StockQuantity;
        //    else
        //        QBItem.QtyOnHand = 0;
        //}

        QBItem.PurchaseDesc = _ItemName;
        //QBItem.SalesDesc = _ItemName;
        QBItem.PurchaseCost = new Money() { Amount = _OrderItem.Product.PurchaseCost };
        //QBItem.SalesPrice = (Double)_OrderItem.UnitPriceExclTax;
        QBItem.IncomeAccountRef = new AccountRef { AccountName = _qboSettings.ItemIncomeAcct };
        QBItem.COGSAccountRef = new AccountRef() { AccountName = _qboSettings.ItemCOGSAcct };
        QBItem.AssetAccountRef = new AccountRef() { AccountName = _qboSettings.ItemAssetAcct };

        try
        {
            Item it = dataServices.Add(QBItem);
            return it;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessageDataSource.Insert(new ErrorMessage(MessageSeverity.Error, "QBO", String.Format("Error adding item : {0}", ex.ToString())));
            return new Item();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Please log the request/response XML and post it. http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0200_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/0600_Logging

Comment: Also, it this QBD or QBO?  Item Create is not supported in QBD. http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0050_Data_Services/v2/0500_QuickBooks_Windows/0500_Supported_Objects

Comment: Thanks. I needed to specify the QBItem.Type variable:             QBItem.Type = ItemTypeEnum.Inventory;
QBItem.TypeSpecified = true;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question (from Joseph)
Specify the QBItem.Type variable: QBItem.Type = ItemTypeEnum.Inventory; QBItem.TypeSpecified = true;

thanks
Jarred